# simplest possible .ajax-call to twitter search-api?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying call twitter. What is the simplest working call to the twitter-search-api?

This is what I have tired. The call fails.
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url:  "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=skjutsgruppen&callback=?",
    })

Comment: if you do it that way i think you need to either specify dataType as `jsonp` or omit dataType completely so it works its magic internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=stackoverflow", 
  function (r) {
    console.log(r);
});
```